# How to change jumplist behavior?

Tags: jumplist

See the following example:

```
" open a file with 20+ lines.
1gg    " jump to line 1
3gg    " jump to line 3
5gg    " jump to line 5
7gg    " jump to line 7
ctrl+O " back to line 5
ctrl+O " back to line 3
20gg   " jump to line 20
ctrl+O " back to line 3
ctrl+O " back to line 7!!!! But what I expected is back to line 1
```

I read [`:h jumplist`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#jumplist) and know why I get this result.
But this behavior is really annoying for me (I use Vim to read c++ code and jump through function call stack frequently), what I want is:

After `ctrl+O` and make a new jump, vim can erases jump tags that are later than current position in the jumplist.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but are you already aware of the `CTRL-T` command? It goes back in the tag stack, which works differently from the jumplist and (I think) closer to what you want.

Comment: @Rich I didn't known ctrl-t before and just tried it,  I would say ctrl-t does help a lot, the behavior for tag stack is what I want for jumplist.  However, ctrl-t is limited for tag stack, sometimes I stiil have the need for ctrl+O, but each ctrl+] adds an element in jumplist, which makes it annoying to use ctrl+O to go back.

Comment: I have the same problem. It's really annoying, Please someone can give any help.
eg. Clean jump lists after ctrl+o.

Comment: This is not possible I think, i.e. there is no settings to achieve that. And this would not be desirable for most people cause we use `ctrl+i` for going forward in jumplist. And if you just clear the later jumps from the current position, you can't use `ctrl+i`. So, it will never be the official behavior. But you can maybe use `:h getjumplist()` to create your own plugin with your wanted behavior.

Answer (score 10):

Neovim has now a [jumplist-stack](https://neovim.io/doc/user/motion.html#jumplist-stack) setting that makes the jumplist behave like the tag stack:

```
set jumpoptions+=stack
```

For Vim, this is available in [version 9.0.1921](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/87018255e3ad0f4dfa03e20318836d24af721caf) or higher.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem as yours, which annoyed me years. Now I add a [trimjumplist](https://github.com/sevenever/vim/pull/1) function to vim so I can use below code and it works for me but you will have to compile vim. Hope this will help.

```
function! TrimJumpListAndCscopeFind(action, word)
    if has('jumplist')
        if exists('*trimjumplist')
            let jl = getjumplist()
            call trimjumplist(len(jl[0]) - str2nr(jl[1]))
        endif
    endif
    call CscopeFind(a:action, a:word)
endfunction

nnoremap  <leader>fg :call TrimJumpListAndCscopeFind('g', expand('<cword>'))<CR>
```

Comment: Hi sevenever! On Stackexchange sites, it is good practice to avoid answers of the kind "I have this problem too", and "link only" answers. That's the reason I proposed an edit with the content of the function you have created that is on github. Feel free to add more detailed information.